# Allow/Denny logOnHours in AD using powerShell issue

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a PS script that running by Task Scheduler and Allow/Denny logOnHours in AD for users by their starting date (stored in extensionAttribute).
Ths issue is that not all the users that need to be allowed are allowed (e.g from 10 new employees starting today, only 6 are allowed and all others stay as Denied).

This is my script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$Logfile = "c:\mypath.txt"

Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)
   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

$date = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
$message = $date + ' - Running Allow/Denny script' 
LogWrite $message

Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$currentDate = (Get-Date).Date
[dateTime]$startingDate = 0
$SearchBase = "OU=Users,DC=DC,DC=my"
$logonhoursAllow=@{"Logonhours"= [byte[]]$hours=@(255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255)}
$logonhoursDeny=@{"Logonhours"= [byte[]]$hours=@(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)}

Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties extensionAttribute1 -Filter {(extensionAttribute1 -like '*')} | ForEach-Object {
    if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($_.extensionAttribute1, 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null, 'None', [ref]$startingDate)) {
        if ($startingDate -eq $currentDate) {
          $message = 'LogOnHours Enabled for: ' + $_.SamAccountName
          LogWrite $message
          Set-ADUSer -identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace $logonHoursAllow 
        }
        elseif($startingDate -gt $currentDate) {
          $message = 'LogOnHours Disabled for: ' + $_.SamAccountName
          LogWrite $message
          Set-ADUSer -identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace $logonHoursDeny
        }
    }
    else {
          $message = $($_.SamAccountName) + " has bad value in attribute and no affected from this script." 
          LogWrite $message
        
    }
}
```

Additionally, that's what I see when I'm checking the logonHours attribute:
[image]

In TS script running with `-executionpolicy bypass`

Any idea?

Comment: When setting an ldap attribute using `-Replace`, you need to use the proper casing for the attribute name in the hashtable, which in this case is `logonHours`, not `Logonhours`. This is a VERY tricky attribute to set though and I would advise you to use the [Set LogonHours function](http://www.rlmueller.net/SetLogonHours.htm) by Richard L. Mueller before you simply set all bytes to either 255 or 0..

Comment: I have updated the attribute name, followed the guide you attached and fixed my script a bit to:
 [byte[]]$logonhoursAllow=(255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255)
[byte[]]$logonhoursDeny=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

Now it's working as expected, thanks!